# Linux bash forking process (inotifywait)

Tags: linux, bash

I have a running bash script that is forking.
It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/killall inotifywait

/usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder1/ | while IFS= read -r FILE; do /bin/chmod 770 "$FILE"; done >/dev/null 2>&1 &
/usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder2/ | while IFS= read -r FILE; do /bin/chmod 770 "$FILE"; done >/dev/null 2>&1 &
/usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder3/ | while IFS= read -r FILE; do /bin/chmod 770 "$FILE"; done >/dev/null 2>&1 &
/usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder4/ | while IFS= read -r FILE; do /bin/chmod 770 "$FILE"; done >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If i run the script it creates 8 processes:

- /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder1/...
- /bin/bash ./scriptname.sh
- /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder2/...
- /bin/bash ./scriptname.sh
- /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder3/...
- /bin/bash ./scriptname.sh
- /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder4/...
- /bin/bash ./scriptname.sh

Why does it not forking like this?

- /bin/bash ./scriptname.sh

  - /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder1/...
  - /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder2/...
  - /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder3/...
  - /usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/sftp/folder4/...

Thank you for your answer,
starflighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are piping output of inotifywait into a while loop. That while loop in this context will run in a subshell, which is what these extra bash processes are.